# functions executed once and addEventlistener has no effect

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events, addeventlistener

I am manipulating the background color of 3 table cells depending on `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup` events. 
**html**

```
<table border="1px">
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Action</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Keydown</td><td id="down"></td><td id="downvalue"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Keypress</td><td id="press"></td><td id="pressvalue"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Keyup</td><td id="up"></td><td id="upvalue"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="txt" /><br />
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("Keydown", keyisdown(), false);
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("Keyup", keyisup(), false);
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("Keypress", keyispress(), false);
}

function keyisdown()
{
 document.getElementById("press").style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
 document.getElementById("up").style.backgroundColor = "white";
 document.getElementById("down").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
// above function is repeated twice for keyisup and keyispress
```

I am supposed to type into the field, and change the background color respectively, but all run once upon page load or refresh and never again, how can i solve that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First error is that you are executing the functions on `window.load`. only pass name of the function to the eventListener, remove `()` after the function name.

Second: Use `.onkeydown` instead of attaching an event listener.

Third: I hope that you are not trying to change color of the cells on pressing arrowkeyup and arrowkeydown. The functions `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` do not register which key was pressed. You have to use `.keyCode` for that.

In the below example I have only included `.onkeydown` function which changes color of down to green when arrowkeyup is pressed, and to red when arrowkeydown is pressed.

```js
window.onload = function()
{

document.getElementById("txt").onkeydown =   function(e){
  document.getElementById("press").style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
  document.getElementById("up").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  var code = e.keyCode;
  if(code==40){
    document.getElementById("down").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else if(code==38){
    document.getElementById("down").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Action</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Keydown</td><td id="down"></td><td id="downvalue"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Keypress</td><td id="press"></td><td id="pressvalue"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Keyup</td><td id="up"></td><td id="upvalue"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="txt"/><br />
```

Comment: Hey Kitty, I have executed the functions without `window.onload`, removed the function paranthesis, basically tried everything before i asked here,nothing is working. I am hoping to fix the problem i have ( it's basically from a video tutorial) rather than doing it another way! thanks anyways.

Comment: upvoted for the tip on removing the paranthesis, it wasn't the main issue but it also helped,thx.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("keydown", keyisdown, false);
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("keyup", keyisup, false);
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("keypress", keyispress, false);
}

function keyisdown()
{
 document.getElementById("press").style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
 document.getElementById("up").style.backgroundColor = "white";
 document.getElementById("down").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
function keyisup()
{
 document.getElementById("press").style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
 document.getElementById("up").style.backgroundColor = "red";
 document.getElementById("down").style.backgroundColor = "white";
} 

function keyispress()
{
 document.getElementById("press").style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
 document.getElementById("up").style.backgroundColor = "white";
 document.getElementById("down").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Action</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Keydown</td><td id="down"></td><td id="downvalue"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Keypress</td><td id="press"></td><td id="pressvalue"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Keyup</td><td id="up"></td><td id="upvalue"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="txt" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,basically i used another IDE, and things worked fine! It seems the one i was using was buggy. [ Also paranthesis `()` had to be removed as stated by user KittyCat below.]

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Here you have all you need to know to use addEventListener

In some old browsers this is not supported.

You can do something similar to addEventListener:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
element.onclick = function () {
    // 
}
```